# How to make underscore separate into space separate?

Tags: linux

I have the following data:

```
ID  Affection   rs3117294   rs2747453   rs2747454   rs2747457   rs3131888
D0024949    0   C_C A_G A_G A_A A_G
D0024302    0   A_C A_A A_G A_A A_A
D0023151    0   C_C A_G A_A A_A G_G
D0022042    0   A_C A_A G_G A_A A_A
D0021275    0   C_C A_G A_G A_A A_G
D0021163    0   A_A A_A G_G A_A A_A
D0020795    0   A_A A_A G_G A_C A_G
D0020691    0   A_A A_A G_G A_C A_G
D0019121    0   A_A A_A G_G C_C G_G
```

I want to make the underscore a space, so that C_C to be C C.

How can I do that? Please make the code general to apply it to the whole data I have.

I got the following from someone "not my code"  `sed '1d' plink.raw | sed 's/_/ /g' > plinkv2.raw`, but it gave me empty cells the data is not complete.

Comment: i got the following from someone "not my code"     sed '1d' plink.raw | sed 's/_/ /g' > plinkv2.raw, but it gave me empty cells the data is not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `sed`:

```
sed -itmp 's/\(\w\)_\(\w\)/\1 \2/g' file
```

This will overwrite `file` and save a backup of original to `file.tmp`.

POSIX `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)_\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g' file > file2
```

You have to redirect to another file. Copy `file2` to the original if that's what you want.

Both use the concept of "back-references". Surrounding text with `\(`..`\)` in the pattern makes it available in the substitution with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Comment: can you put a tab instead of the space?

Comment: Just replace the space with `\t`. Since your question asks for space I need to leave the answer consistent with that so as not to confuse other people.

Comment: between the \1 and \2 ??

Comment: it gave me AtC , no tab !

Comment: a separated by a tab b...

Comment: could you please write the part of the code with the tab maybe i'm writing something wrong

Comment: @BLayer Some `sed` implementations don't support `\t` et al. At least one of my systems requires a literal tab (it may be NetBSD, but I am not completely sure). Dollar-quotes would work too

Comment: So Marwah try an actual tab character (hit the Tab key) instead of `\t`. Or perhaps Ctrl+I would work.

Comment: @Fox When you say dollar-quotes I think `$'\t'` but how would one put that in the substitution?

Comment: @BLayer i tried but the tab key is not working in the terminal (I use MAC) anyway Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Oh, try `Ctrl-V Tab`. Just read something about it. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/sed-not-recognizing-t-instead-it-is-treating-it-as-t-why

Comment: @BLayer Either `sed 's/…/\1'$'\t''\2/'` or `sed $'s/…/\\1\t\\2'`. Neither looks particularly good, so I tend to just use the literal tab. Ctrl-v Ctrl-i is fewer keystrokes than any of these alternatives

Comment: @Fox yeah I was just reading about that approach in the page I linked! Thanks, by the way, for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find the below command and output
```

it replaces _ with spaces through out the file

```
awk '{gsub("_"," ",$0);print $0}' j.txt 
D0024949    0   C C A G A G A A A G
D0024302    0   A C A A A G A A A A
D0023151    0   C C A G A A A A G G
D0022042    0   A C A A G G A A A A
D0021275    0   C C A G A G A A A G
D0021163    0   A A A A G G A A A A
D0020795    0   A A A A G G A C A G
D0020691    0   A A A A G G A C A G
D0019121    0   A A A A G G C C G G
```

IF want it to be replace only first match

sed "s/_/ /1" inputfile

Let us know for any clarification kindly provide the proper input and output